# How to make table columns width dynamic?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

How can I make table column width change dynamically according to the data inside the columns?
(I define table width 100% because that the columns width behave different).

Comment: What have you already tried that's failed?

Comment: You need to post some code before anyone can help.

Comment: @Yosef, that is the default behavior of table columns. Perhaps your parent object is constricting the table's width?

Comment: I define table width 100% because that its not default

Comment: Then that's why it doesn't work. Remove the width on the table and the columns will enlarge only to the size of their content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the `nowrap` attribute for a `td` element.  More information [here](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/_TD_NOWRAP.html).  Something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td nowrap>
      This is a long sentence which constitutes a lot of data that shouldn't wrap when rendered.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s3pvc/).

Answer (score 0):

It is by default...that it set the column width according to column content, it sets to maximum content length in that particular column.

Comment: I define table width 100% because that its not default

Comment: @Yosef Setting the table with to 100% just tells the table to occupy 100% of the width of the parent. If you dont have the parent set with a width it wont do you any good.